# How to make a particular data go to the top of listview - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have several data in my listview and i want to check if any of the data satisfies this if condition, let it stay at the top of the listview at 0 index.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: boolS == true ? 7 : data.length,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) {
    if (boolS == true) {
      return shimmer();
    }
    var index = data[idx];
    if (index.userId == userId) {
      // make the data stay at the top
    }
    return Container(
        ///....
    );
),
```

Please how do i achieve this. I tried adding this to the listview

```
itemCount: boolS == true ? 7 : data.length + 1,
///...
if(idx == 0 && index.userId == userId) {
   return Container();
}
```

but i don't think that's gonna work. So please can you guys help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (index.userId == userId) {
    // make the data stay at the top
    data.insert(0, index);
    data.removeAt(idx+1);
    }
```